# PHP: How do I get the URL of the link that was clicked not the URL of the refering site?

Tags: php, redirect, request, http-referer

How do I get the URL of the clicked link, not the URL of the referring site with PHP?

I understand that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give me the URL of the referring page, but how do I get the URL of the link that was clicked on the page?

For example:

If you were on google and you got a search result that took you to `example.com/search_results_link.php`, how do I get the `example.com/search_results_link.php` as the URL you clicked on to get to my site and not as just the referring domain of `google.com` from using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the site that the user ends up on? What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: if you want your full url you can get it by `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"`

Comment: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] -- that gives me the URL of the page Im on. Im looking for the url of the link that brought me to this page.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can either get the site containing the link, or you actual URL, but not all the redirections in the middle.

Comment: You can't. You can get the referer (if the client lets you) and nothing more unless you have control over the page with the link.

Comment: ok then, let me try and rephrase the question: You know when you click a link, to lets say for example forbes.com, when you click the link it takes you to an advertisement page and its got a link to take you to the page your were trying to get to before the ad page intercepted you. So how do they do this if you cant get the URL of the link that sent you to the page?

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment then; you can't.